# Salt Stack Reporting - Executing commands based on environment

Tags: configuration-management, salt

Salt allows users to assign machines to environments by setting in /etc/salt/minion:

```
environment: example
```

You can then execute environments for that state with the command `salt '*' state.apply saltenv=example`

However, it appears that the same cannot be said for an arbitrary command. Running `salt '*' cmd.run 'df -h' saltenv=example` will run on all minions instead of just the minions in the "example" environment. How can I run commands for only a specified environment?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is that you can't directly. You have to set a grain on the minions first by doing something similar to:

```
salt '*' cmd.run 'grep environment /etc/salt/minion | awk "{print \"environment: \" \$2}" >> /etc/salt/grains'
salt '*' saltutil.sync_grains
salt -G environment:prod cmd.run 'df -h'
```